# Is a Sigma AF 28-80 an useful addition to a Nikkor 35-105 macro?

Tags: lens, zoom, normal

I'm experimenting with photography and I'm on a budget: I'm using a Nikon D70 and I already have a Nikkor AF 35-105 f/3.5-4.5 macro and a 50 mm f/1.8 E (manual focus).

Now I found a cheap Sigma AF 28-80 f/3.5-5.6, that I understand being a kit lens for older film cameras. The reason I'd like to buy it is to get a slightly wider lens for casual photography.

Is the difference in wide angle worth the purchase? It's also slower on the longer focals, but that's a smaller concern.

Comment: Maybe this tool can help you to decide weather the additional 7mm of focal length are worth the price: http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/simulator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement your 35-105, I'd suggest a wide angle zoom, like a Sigma 10-20 or Tamron/Nikkor 10-24 or the likes. However, it depends on how much on a budget you are as the Sigma/Tamron are still in the 350-400€ range new (at least).

If those lenses are out of your budget, consider the 18-55 kit lens (VR or not) which is available used at cheap prices (below 100€ used) and has fantastic performance for its price.

Comment: In fact a 18-55 would be a good idea price-wise. Since the D70 has a built-in AF motor, are there 18-55s without motor?

Comment: As far as I know modern kit lenses have motors (even the 18-70 which was bundled with the D70 itself). You can still use lenses with motors with the D70 and lenses without motor aren't usually significantly cheaper than ones with it (the only exception being the 50mm f/1.8 which is a lot cheaper without).. so I'd ignore the motor issue.

Answer (score 2):

For that small of a gain, you'd probably be better off with a wide angle prime lens.  You gain a very minimal amount of additional range and if it is a lens designed for film cameras it is going to have ghosting problems on digital bodies due to the lack of internal anti-reflective coatings.